# UITableView scrolling not smooth due to NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, nsattributedstring, smooth-scrolling

I am using `NSAttributedString` for converting html string to `attributedString`. I have converted it but `label` in cell so i have write below code in `cellForRowAtIndex`,when i apply this code tableview not scrolling smooth . If i remove this with simple text it scrolling smoothly .

```
 cell.lblDescription.setHTMLFromString(htmlText: model.strItineraryDescription)
```

I have convert `html string` to `attributed string`

```
extension UILabel {

    func setHTMLFromString(htmlText: String) {
        let modifiedFont = NSString(format:"<span style=\"font-family: '-apple-system', 'HelveticaNeue'; font-size: \(self.font!.pointSize)\">%@</span>" as NSString, htmlText) as String


        //process collection values
        let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
            data: modifiedFont.data(using: .unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
            options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
            documentAttributes: nil)


        self.attributedText = attrStr
    }

}
```

My `html string` is

```
<strong><u>Featured Program</u></strong></p>
\n<ol>
\n  <li>Arrival at Delhi airport. You will receive by our representative.</li>
\n  <li>Driving to Agra and exploring the city.</li>
\n  <li>Back to Hotel for Overnight stay.</li>
\n</ol>
\n<p><strong>City Features</strong></p>
\n<ol>
\n  <li><strong>Visit to Agra Fort \U2013 </strong>Former Name Badalgarh, Shah-Jahan spent his last eight years here. You can watch the mesmerizing view of Taj Mahal from this fort just like Shah Jahan.</li>
\n  <li><strong>Visit to Taj Mahal \U2013</strong> It took 21 years to build and stood in 1653. The palace is considered as the symbol of love. Shah Jahan built this wonder in the memory of his wife Mumtaj Mahal.</li>
\n</ol>
\n<p><strong>(Both Agra Fort and Taj Mahal are UNESCO Declared world heritage site)</strong>
```

Comment: Answer from NeverHopeless is the perfect way to implement your requirement. @NeverHopeless nice one!!! +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does this `html2AttributedString` do ? Does it convert HTML to attributed string on the fly on `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ? If yes, this is what actually taking time. Can we compromise on memory to speed up by cache the HTML's equivalent attributed string in another variable in the model. So this way on reloading it will fetch the prepared attributed string during either cell creation or reuse.

e.g., Psuedocode:

```
class MyModel
{
    var myHTML: String = ""
    var myHTML2AttributedString: String = ""
}


class ModelMapping
{
  ...
  myModel.myHTML = responseFromJSON["htmlText"]
  myModel.myHTML2AttributedString = customFuncToConvertHTMLToAttributed(myModel.myHTML)
  ...
}

class ViewController
{
  ...
  cell.lblDescription.attributedText = myModel.myHTML2AttributedString // This one would be cached Attributed string equivalent of HTML string.
  ...
}
```

Hope that helps!

**EDIT**:

```
class MyModel
{
    var myAttributedHTML: NSMutableAttributedString = ""
    var strItineraryDescription: String = ""

    func prepareHTMLFromString() {
        let modifiedFont = NSString(format:"<span style=\"font-family: '-apple-system', 'HelveticaNeue'; font-size: \(self.font!.pointSize)\">%@</span>" as NSString, self.strItineraryDescription) as String


        //process collection values
        let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(
            data: modifiedFont.data(using: .unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!,
            options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
            documentAttributes: nil)


        myAttributedHTML = attrStr.mutableCopy()
    }
}

class MyViewController
{
   ...
   cell.lblDescription.attributedText = myModel.myAttributedHTML
   ...
}

class ResponseHandler
{
   ...
   myModel.strItineraryDescription = responseFromServer["myHTML"]
   myModel.prepareHTMLFromString()
   ...
}
```

Comment: @VinodKumar, ok, what am i saying here is don't prepare your attributed string at a time of displaying in cell, instead prepare it at the same time when you get value of `model.strItineraryDescription`, and on display call `cell.lblDescription.yourPropertyInModelObjectThatContainsAttributedString`. Got it ?

Comment: I also have done in this way but not work. Please help me   @NeverHopeless

Comment: @VinodKumar, Check my edited answer does it help you ? Also, what happens when you comment this line ` cell.lblDescription.setHTMLFromString(htmlText: model.strItineraryDescription)` does it work as expected ?

Comment: Your edited answer work for me, Thank You @NeverHopeless

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Dispatch queue

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    print("This is run on the background queue")
    let strmy = model.strItineraryDescription.html2AttributedString            

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell.lblDescription.attributedText = strmy

    }
}
```

Comment: now my cell height not increasing , i am using estimated height . @KKRocks
       `tblView.estimatedRowHeight = 185.0
        tblView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`